# How to send data to MongoDB that is calculated after page loads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Node.js with Express and MongoDB.

I have a page, `'/score'` that calculates the user's score from a quiz taken on the previous page. The `'/score'` route is below:

```
app.get('/score', stormpath.getUser, function(req, res) {
    var quiz = req.session.mostRecentQuiz;
    db.collection('quizzes').find(quiz).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        var quiz;
          docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            quiz = doc.quiz;
        });
        res.render('score', {quiz: quiz});
    });
    db.collection('users').update({user: req.user.username}, { $set: {"mostRecentQuiz": quiz } }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    } );
});
```

After getting the quiz answers from the DB, I use some client-side JavaScript on the /score page to calculate the user's score and then report it to the user. However, I would like to get that same score back to my MongoDB, but I am not sure how best to accomplish that.

Can I use AJAX to accomplish this, or would it be better to redirect to a new page?

Comment: If the score computation can be made server-side, do so, save it in the db, then return the pre-calculated score back to the frontend. All of this, in one request.

Comment: If you really need to do the computation on the front-end, you could effectively use ajax to send back data to another url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Express, the simplest way would be to define a route for updating the score. Then you can send the data to the server via AJAX.
In order to parse the request parameters install the `body-parser` module.

Server:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.put('/score', stormpath.getUser, function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body); // there should be your received data

  // save it to the database
  db.collection('yourcollection').updateOne(
      {}, // your query for updating the data in the wished field
      function(err, results) {
        if(err) { return res.json(err); }; 
        return res.json(results);
   });
});
```

Client - if you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/score',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {'score':1000}, // put here your data to send it to the server
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Some documentation:

MongoDB update: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/update/

jQuery AJAX: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/